# Obtain values from array in one class from another class

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code in a class and want to ideally copy the values in the `adjclose` array list to another class for further process while preserving the original data.

I am able to see that the arraylist is populated with the values with the `println` statement prior to the `return` statement as the array is being populated.

The `main` method then iterates through the arraylist to again show the values for each element in the arraylist `adjclose`.

How can I get to the `adjclose` arraylist from another class to enable me to copy them to a new arraylist to process further?

```
public ArrayList<Double> getadjClose(String symbol) {
    String baseUrl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?ignore=.csv";
    baseUrl += "&s=" + symbol;
    baseUrl += "&a=" + startMonth;
    baseUrl += "&b=" + startDay;
    baseUrl += "&c=" + startYear;
    baseUrl += "&d=" + endMonth;
    baseUrl += "&e=" + endDay;
    baseUrl += "&f=" + endYear;
    baseUrl += "&g=" + freq;
    URL url;
    ArrayList<Double> adjclose = new ArrayList<Double>();
    System.out.print("Opening URL: ");
    System.out.print(baseUrl);
    System.out.println(" ");
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        url = new URL(baseUrl);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));
        in.readLine(); // Forward Header
        while (true) {
            String thisLine = in.readLine();
            if (thisLine == null) {
                break;
            }
            String[] separatedLine = thisLine.split("[,X]"); // split by commas
            adjclose.add(Double.parseDouble(separatedLine[6]));
            System.out.println(adjclose.get(counter) + " " + counter);
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        return adjclose;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have now made the changes to the code within the first class and it appears as follows.

```
package yahooapi;

/**
 *
 * @author RSLOMA
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class YahooAPI {


int startMonth;
int startDay;
int startYear;

int endMonth;
int endDay;
int endYear;
int TodayDate;

String freq;

public ArrayList<Double> data = new ArrayList<>();


public ArrayList<Double>  getAdjClose(String symbol) throws IOException {
String baseUrl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?ignore=.csv";
baseUrl += "&s=" + symbol;
baseUrl += "&a=" + startMonth;
baseUrl += "&b=" + startDay;
baseUrl += "&c=" + startYear;
baseUrl += "&d=" + endMonth;
baseUrl += "&e=" + endDay;
baseUrl += "&f=" + endYear;
baseUrl += "&g=" + freq;

URL url;

// use a local variable

ArrayList<Double> adjclose = new ArrayList<>(); 

System.out.print("Opening URL: ");
System.out.print(baseUrl);
System.out.println(" ");

int counter = 0;

try {
url = new URL(baseUrl);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

in.readLine(); //Forward Header

while (true){
String thisLine = in.readLine();
if (thisLine == null){
break;
}
String[] separatedLine = thisLine.split("[,X]"); // split by commas

adjclose.add(Double.parseDouble(separatedLine[6]));
System.out.println(adjclose.get(counter) + " " + counter);

// update the data once the read is done

data = adjclose;
System.out.println(data.get(counter));

counter = counter + 1;

}


return adjclose;

} catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
}
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
YahooAPI y = new YahooAPI();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

y.startDay = 1;
y.startMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1; //0 is jan, so 2 is march
y.startYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 3;
System.out.println("Day: " + y.startMonth);
System.out.println("Day: " + y.startDay);
System.out.println("Day: " + y.startYear);

y.endDay = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) - (cal.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
y.endMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); //0 is jan, so 2 is march
y.endYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

y.freq = "m"; // d for daily frequency, w for weekly, m for monthly

ArrayList<Double> adjclose = y.getAdjClose("^GSPC");

//Iterator<Double> iter = adjclose.iterator();

//System.out.println("Returned Adjusted Close Values:");
//while (iter.hasNext()){
//System.out.println(iter.next());


int ArrayLngth = adjclose.size();

System.out.print("Array length = " + ArrayLngth + "    ");
}

    public ArrayList<Double> getAdjClose() {

        for (int counter = 0; counter<data.size(); counter++) {

            System.out.println(data.get(counter) + " " + counter);

    }



        return (ArrayList<Double>) data.clone();


    }



}
```

I have another class in another package that I want to use for calculations, retain the original data elements in the original array, and save the new calculated data in an array in the 2nd class.  The beginning code for the other class is below.  How do I call to obtain the data that is cloned in data.clone()?

```
package PortfolioDesign;

/**
 *
 * @author RSLOMA
 */


public class MonthlyReturns {


        }
```

Comment: Didn't get your question properly. If you need to call this method from other class, just create an object of this class and call the public method with the dot operator, that will do.

Comment: he said that he didn't want the second class's operations to affect the object in the first, hence the need for a clone

Answer (score 1):

Have a method in your first class that will create a clone of the array and return the clone, then call that method from your second class.

Answer (score 1):

If a result is used multiple times, I would split the method into

- a data collector method
- a data retrieval method

The data collector then fills a member of the class:

```
private ArrayList<Double> data = new ArrayList<Double>();

public void  fillAdjClose(String symbol) throws IOException {
    String baseUrl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?ignore=.csv";
    baseUrl += "&s=" + symbol;
    baseUrl += "&a=" + startMonth;
    baseUrl += "&b=" + startDay;
    baseUrl += "&c=" + startYear;
    baseUrl += "&d=" + endMonth;
    baseUrl += "&e=" + endDay;
    baseUrl += "&f=" + endYear;
    baseUrl += "&g=" + freq;
    URL url;

    // use a local variable
    ArrayList<Double> adjclose = new ArrayList<Double>();
    System.out.print("Opening URL: ");
    System.out.print(baseUrl);
    System.out.println(" ");
    int counter = 0;
    url = new URL(baseUrl);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            url.openStream()));
    in.readLine(); // Forward Header
    while (true) {
        String thisLine = in.readLine();
        if (thisLine == null) {
            break;
        }
        String[] separatedLine = thisLine.split("[,X]"); // split by commas
        adjclose.add(Double.parseDouble(separatedLine[6]));
        System.out.println(adjclose.get(counter) + " " + counter);
        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    // update the date once the read is done
    data = adjclose;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getAdjClose() {
    return (ArrayList<Double>) data.clone();
}
```

You can call getAdjClose() as often you want and always get a copy of the last read data.

You can always use clone() for an ArrayList unless you also need copies of the elements. Since you are using Double, which is immutable, there is no need to copy the elements.

Comment: I see how this works in the code shown.  I still do not get how to call the getAdjClose() or clone() in the second class.  Could you give me an example?

Comment: I should add that the 2nd class is contained within a different package.  But I am assuming that the class' package will be imported.

Comment: Let's assume you have the code above in a "class DataCollector {...}" then you instantiate it with "DataCollector dc = new DataCollector();" and fill it "dc.fillAdjClose("whatever");". You need to preserve the instance somehow, e.g. "context.setDataCollector(sc)" or use a static variable "public static DataCollector lastDc;" and put it there "lastDc = dc;". Now you can access the instance to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish the values of `adjclose` say from `Class A` to `Class B` then the containing class `ClassA` should ideally have a getter method which can be called my `ClassB`.

To preserve the original data you should publish a copy of `adjClose` and not the original list itself. Also to note, you should do a deep clone and not shallow clone.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
public classA {
   private List<Double> adjclose = null;

   public List<Double> getAdjClose(){
     List<Double> returnValue = new ArrayList<Double>();
     if(adjclose != null) {
        returnValue.addAll(adjclose); // this will ensure that if caller makes any changes to adjClose, copy of classA remains intact.
        return returnValue;
     }
     return Collections.emptyList();
   }    
}
```

The caller class ClassB will then make an instance of ClassA and call getAdjClose() on it.

```
import java.util.List;
public class ClassB {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassA classA = new ClassA();
      List<Double> list = classA.getAdjClose();
      System.out.println(list);
      list.set(0, new Double(11));
      System.out.println(list);
      System.out.println(classA.getAdjClose());
   }
}
```